# Running a list through a less than to produce shorter list python

Tags: python

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
for x in a:
  list(x < 4):
```

Expected Output:  `[0,1,2,3]`
Actual Output:  `[True, True, True, True, False, False, False]`

Any idea how to get what I want?

Comment: The list is always sorted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
print ([x for x in a if x<4])
```

Output;

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Edit after comment: It's called [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

Comment: You may want to mention that the name for this Python feature is a "list comprehension," in case the asker wants to search and learn more about it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `filter`:

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x < 4, a))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

or `itertools.takewhile` (in case the list was **sorted**):

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list(takewhile(lambda x: x < 4, a))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: What is the list is not sorted?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you are right, added it to the answer.